# Homophone riddle 8

Tags: riddle, word

It feels like such a long time that I didn't post one...

```
 It might be something 10 feet away from you
 Or it could be a verb
 In movies, this would be an escape route
 I chose these because of me
```

Comment: Wait, homophone or homonym???

Comment: Homophone, if you saw my other 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a

> Duct

It might be something 10 feet away from you

> they're common in most buildings?

Or it could be a verb

> "I Ducked" or maybe it's a ventilation duct and I "vented"

In movies, this would be an escape route

> Escape through a noisy thin metal tunnel because the aliens/zombies/bad-guys are hard of hearing in Hollywood

I chose these because of me

> Duck-t

Comment: Homophone of... rot13[qhpxrq] :P

Comment: Yes! I knew the "I chose these because of me" was a dead giveaway

Comment: I actually got it from the movie escape route more than anything

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> CEILING / SEALING?

It might be something 10 feet away from you

> The ceiling is about 10 feet from the ground.

Or it could be a verb

> "Sealing", that is *to seal* something is a verb, and a homophone because they are pronounced the same.

In movies, this would be an escape route

> I'm sure I've seen movies where people have escaped through the ducts in the ceiling.

I chose these because of me

> Well, your name is *Duck*. This could either because you have to "duck" for a low ceiling (or if you crawled through a ceiling space); or perhaps because of the "ducts" that run through ceilings?

Comment: At the end:  Or for the tape?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer is supposed to be a homophone, I found a homonym that fits all the descriptions

> Water

It might be something 10 feet away from you

> Well, there's a sewer right outside of my house and it has water

Or it could be a verb

> Water as a verb like to "water" plants

In movies, this would be an escape route

> Well, many actors jump into the water when they have to escape from a ship in a movie

I chose these because of me

> Ducks, just like your beautiful name, swim in water

Comment: nice answer, but that isn't a homophone though

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid Yea, I know it's not. But it fits everything right? XD

Comment: Sorry, nope! Think about homophones and movies

Comment: @Duck Well, back to the beginning then :D

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a

> pole/poll?

It might be something 10 feet away from you

> One end of it, at least, since a 10-ft. pole is the measuring device for things you want to keep away, as in the phrase "I wouldn't touch that soup with a ten foot pole."

Or it could be a verb

> To take a survey is to poll a group.

In movies, this would be an escape route

> Because real firefighters don't use them to get down from high places, but fictional people are often portrayed as doing so.

I chose these because of me

> You are not really a duck. You are a decoy, and thus could use one of [these](https://www.bbwaterfowl.com/blank-2/duck-pole-12-pack) to support yourself. (I see no evidence that you are from Poland, or I would have gone with that.)

Answer (score 0):

May it be...

> stairs / stares

It might be something 10 feet away from you

> In a house or in most of the buildings

Or it could be a verb

> It is, and it may also be rude :)

In movies, this would be an escape route

> Often, when bad guys (or policemen according to the kind of movies) reach the front door

I chose these because of me

> You are not a real duck, like WAF said... so I think you have a fix gaze... a stare!